# How to rename downloaded file in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have managed to download a csv file in puppeteer, but it is generated with an instant date and time, so I would like to rename it after downloading it. The problem is that, I would not know how to rename it.

I try to see the Content-Disposition but I get "undefined".

```
const [button] = await page.$x("//span[contains(text(), 'DESCARGAR')]");

await Promise.all([

  await button.click(),
     // Event on all responses
      page.on('response', response => {
        const headers = response.headers['Content-Disposition'];

          console.log(headers);
      })
  ]);
```

I wouldn't know how to rename it then. I need your help.

Comment: Rename with a filesystem copy operation where the `dest[ination]` is the renamed filename: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_copyfile_src_dest_flags_callback

Comment: The problem is that I get the download dynamically, I don't know the "source", download something like this: "Keyword Stats 2019-08-18 at 10_20_15.csv"

Comment: Then read the contents of the response into a write operation (stream or otherwise): https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback I don't do node, so I can only point you in the right direction. If you can get to the content, write it to a file with the filename you want.